# Stix, Taxii, Python3, Cabby API - getting data into a format i can use

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm using the cabby API: https://github.com/EclecticIQ/cabby

in hopes of pulling stix info through the taxii client.

I've got my python code pulling the data from www.hailataxii.com

the data is in a container.. and i can flip through it.. it *looks* like xml, but no xml parser will read or manipulate the data. I'd love to put each record into a dictionary, then put the data into some kind of database.. but until i find a way to access the data from the download, i'm at a loss. there is very little data or examples.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my basic code for testing:

```
import pprint

from cabby import create_client

HailATaxiiFeedList=[
    'guest.Abuse_ch',
    'guest.CyberCrime_Tracker',
    'guest.EmergingThreats_rules',
    'guest.Lehigh_edu',
    'guest.MalwareDomainList_Hostlist',
    'guest.blutmagie_de_torExits',
    'guest.dataForLast_7daysOnly',
    'guest.dshield_BlockList',
    'guest.phishtank_com'
]

client = create_client(
    'hailataxii.com',
    use_https=False,
    discovery_path='/taxii-discovery-service')

print (": Discover_Collections:")
services = client.discover_services()
for service in services:
    print('Service type= {s.type} , address= {s.address}' .format(s=service))

print (": Get_Collections:")
collections = client.get_collections(
    uri='http://hailataxii.com/taxii-data')

for collection_name in HailATaxiiFeedList:
    print ("Polling :", collection_name, ".. could take a while, please be patient..")
    file = open(("./iocs/"+ collection_name + ".xml"), "w")
    content_blocks = client.poll(collection_name=collection_name)

    count =1
    for block in content_blocks:
        taxii_message=block.content.decode('utf-8')
        file.write(taxii_message)
        count+=1
        if count > 20: # just getting the 20 top objects because the lists are huge
            break
    file.close()
```

The output looks like xml, but no xml parser will touch it.

```
<stix:STIX_Package xmlns:cyboxCommon="http://cybox.mitre.org/common-2" xmlns:cybox="http://cybox.mitre.org/cybox-2" xmlns:cyboxVocabs="http://cybox.mitre.org/default_vocabularies-2" xmlns:marking="http://data-marking.mitre.org/Marking-1" xmlns:simpleMarking="http://data-marking.mitre.org/extensions/MarkingStructure#Simple-1" xmlns:tlpMarking="http://data-marking.mitre.org/extensions/MarkingStructure#TLP-1" xmlns:TOUMarking="http://data-marking.mitre.org/extensions/MarkingStructure#Terms_Of_Use-1" xmlns:opensource="http://hailataxii.com" xmlns:edge="http://soltra.com/" xmlns:indicator="http://stix.mitre.org/Indicator-2" xmlns:ttp="http://stix.mitre.org/TTP-1" xmlns:stixCommon="http://stix.mitre.org/common-1" xmlns:stixVocabs="http://stix.mitre.org/default_vocabularies-1" xmlns:stix="http://stix.mitre.org/stix-1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:taxii="http://taxii.mitre.org/messages/taxii_xml_binding-1" xmlns:taxii_11="http://taxii.mitre.org/messages/taxii_xml_binding-1.1" xmlns:tdq="http://taxii.mitre.org/query/taxii_default_query-1" id="edge:Package-a2c8f8f2-5a4d-4f0e-92be-d3fa482247d0" version="1.1.1" timestamp="2017-10-09T20:39:36.179672+00:00">
    <stix:STIX_Header>
        <stix:Handling>
            <marking:Marking>
                <marking:Controlled_Structure>../../../../descendant-or-self::node()</marking:Controlled_Structure>
                <marking:Marking_Structure xsi:type="tlpMarking:TLPMarkingStructureType" color="WHITE"/>
                <marking:Marking_Structure xsi:type="TOUMarking:TermsOfUseMarkingStructureType">
                    <TOUMarking:Terms_Of_Use>zeustracker.abuse.ch | Abuse source[https://sslbl.abuse.ch/blacklist/] - As for all abuse.ch projects, the use of the SSL Blacklist is free for both commercial and non-commercial usage without any limitation. However, if you are a commercial vendor of security software/services and you want to integrate data from the SSL Blacklist into your products / services, you will have to ask for permission first by contacting me using the contact form [http://www.abuse.ch/?page_id=4727].'
</TOUMarking:Terms_Of_Use>
                </marking:Marking_Structure>
                <marking:Marking_Structure xsi:type="simpleMarking:SimpleMarkingStructureType">
                    <simpleMarking:Statement>Unclassified (Public)</simpleMarking:Statement>
                </marking:Marking_Structure>
            </marking:Marking>
        </stix:Handling>
    </stix:STIX_Header>
    <stix:Indicators>
        <stix:Indicator id="opensource:indicator-00398022-0d9c-474b-b543-31b85a4f22ab" timestamp="2014-10-31T16:44:24.766014+00:00" xsi:type="indicator:IndicatorType" version="2.1.1">
            <indicator:Title>ZeuS Tracker (offline)| s-k.kiev.ua/html/30/config.bin (2014-10-13) | This domain has been identified as malicious by zeustracker.abuse.ch</indicator:Title>
            <indicator:Type xsi:type="stixVocabs:IndicatorTypeVocab-1.1">Domain Watchlist</indicator:Type>
            <indicator:Type xsi:type="stixVocabs:IndicatorTypeVocab-1.1">URL Watchlist</indicator:Type>
            <indicator:Type xsi:type="stixVocabs:IndicatorTypeVocab-1.1">File Hash Watchlist</indicator:Type>
            <indicator:Description>This domain s-k.kiev.ua has been identified as malicious by zeustracker.abuse.ch. For more detailed infomation about this indicator go to [CAUTION!!Read-URL-Before-Click] [https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php?host=s-k.kiev.ua].</indicator:Description>
            <indicator:Observable idref="opensource:Observable-94ead651-1df5-4cfe-b4bb-e34ce5e60224">
            </indicator:Observable>
            <indicator:Indicated_TTP>
                <stixCommon:TTP idref="opensource:ttp-6055672f-ecfd-40ae-aa84-0b336a5accb6" xsi:type="ttp:TTPType"/>
            </indicator:Indicated_TTP>
            <indicator:Producer>
                <stixCommon:Identity id="opensource:Identity-3066ae12-3db6-44dd-9636-6b083b6479dc">
                    <stixCommon:Name>zeustracker.abuse.ch</stixCommon:Name>
                </stixCommon:Identity>
                <stixCommon:Time>
                    <cyboxCommon:Produced_Time>2014-10-13T00:00:00+00:00</cyboxCommon:Produced_Time>
                    <cyboxCommon:Received_Time>2014-10-20T19:29:30+00:00</cyboxCommon:Received_Time>
                </stixCommon:Time>
            </indicator:Producer>
        </stix:Indicator>
    </stix:Indicators>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this XML, so long as you remember to add the final closing tag:  `</stix:STIX_Package>`.

Comment: From here, you could use an XML tech like XPath to extract the data you want.

Answer (score 2):

The XML you're looking at is STIX. Check out: https://www.eclecticiq.com/stix-taxii. Then follow the link to the STIX website and find (right bottom) "tooling" section. You should find libraries and parsing tools to make it useful.

Alternatively, there are commercial platform available to do data processing magic. Google "Threat Intelligence Platform".

Cheers,
Joep

Founder
EclecticIQ

Comment: try answering the question directly here, rather than just linking

Comment: thank you JOep, i was mixing python libraries from stix1 with data from stix2
There is a huge amount of info on how to put data into stix format.. and how to submit it.. but very little on how to pull data out, parse and process it.. its a slow process but i'm getting there. 

Thank you for your help

Comment: @DarrellMiller can you share your solution....I am kind of facing the same challenge

Comment: I ended up using the open source project opencti to handle the feeds

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using openCTI to handle the feed

Answer (score 0):

NB:Hailataxii.com is discontinued or temporarily unavailable as of 2024. A better alternative is AlienVault